# How is Salesforce able to cater to different customers off the shelf?. -- even with customization

Tags: custom

Have a very naive question on Salesforce..How is a CRM software like Salesforce able to cater to all different kinds of customers off the shelf? For example its customers will have different database schema to be stored and different requirements/processes/workflow…How can we assume that different companies work in the same uniform way?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce, as a CRM, has a lot of things going for it. It's not true that Salesforce can cater to *all* kinds of organizations out of the box, but it can accommodate many of the standard business models out there, either by enabling additional features, customizing standard features, installing packages from the AppExchange, developing custom code to accommodate business rules, and/or the ability to integrate with many different types of external systems, like inventory management, order management, customer support sites, etc.

The main power of Salesforce is that you can customize hundreds of standard options, enable dozens of extra options (many at no cost), and build almost anything you can envision. There are still some really weird edge cases out there where Salesforce simply may not be the appropriate solution for an organization, but those edge cases are exceedingly small. Most businesses do things more or less the same way, and Salesforce has been engineered to support as many standard business models as possible.

Comment: For me the main downside for the platform is a lack of support for computationally expensive synchronous processing. This means you need to sometimes rethink the UX and ensure that the processing is performed asynchronously instead. Other than that (and some weird sh*t on occasion), Salesforce is an excellent platform that takes away many of the day to day concerns.

Comment: @sfdcfox: Thanks!. "ability to integrate with many different types of external systems, like inventory management, order management, customer support sites, etc." => Aren't things like inventory management, order management etc part of Salesforce?. In either case what are some popular softwares for these external work like inventory management, order management etc...

Comment: @grit639 Many organization solutions are complicated, so sometimes they can't/won't replace their already existing system(s), but they want to use Salesforce as well. Salesforce can synchronize and/or access these other systems to keep everything flowing smoothly. Salesforce does this exceptionally well.